# `Vagrant reload --provision` is not copying new project files to the virtual machine

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead, vagrant-provision

I am trying to add a new project to my virtual environment using Homestead. I am using VirtualBox, Vagrant and Homestead installed globally in my Windows 10.

I mapped the project folder in the `~/Homestead/Homestead.yaml` file as shown below and run `vagrant provision` (also tried `vagrant reload --provision` just in case) in the terminal. However, the new project (`project2`) files is not being copied to the virtual machine.

```yaml
# ~/Homestead/Homestead.yaml file
folders:
    - map: E:\path\to\project1
      to: /home/vagrant/project1
    - map: E:\path\to\project2
      to: /home/vagrant/project2

sites:
    - map: proj1.localhost
      to: /home/vagrant/project1/public
      type: "apache"
    - map: proj2.localhost
      to: /home/vagrant/project2/public
      type: "apache"
```

Am I missing something?

I tried to restart the (host) computer (that shut down the virtual machine) and run `vagrant up` again, but it did not work.

As I understand, `vagrant reload --provision` should do the work, but it is not doing it.

Comment: "but it did not work" Describe exactly what is seen or what is happening at this point, what you expect to see and what are you seeing.

Comment: After I run `vagrant up` or `vagrant reload --provision` the virtual machine is booted. I can SSH (using `vagrant SSH` command) into it, but project2 does not exist in the VM. I set up Homestead as I described above, but the project2 is not mounted in the VM, thus I cannot access it via `proj2.localhost` as I should.

Comment: See if you can find something useful in [synced folders section of docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html) (that needs to be set additionally). Also, don't forget to check `/etc/hosts` of host system, something like `192.168.10.10  proj1.localhost` should be there as well.

Comment: Both projects are set in the `hosts` file with the right IP address. I checked the Vagrant file `~/Homestead/.vagrant/machines/homestead/virtualbox/synced_folders` (apparently, it stores the projects' metadata that should be mounted in the VM) and it only has the first project.

Comment: I tried to set the synced folders in the `~/Homestead/VagrantFile`, as you suggested with the link above. It then displayed an error message suggesting that it was not founding the project2 directory, which made me realize that an underscore was missing in the path to project2 (in the `map` key in the `~/Homestead/Homestead.yaml` file). I think Vagrant should also show this error message when reading the settings from the Homestead file, but it doesn't. Thanks for your help @Tpojka.